# Priority HTTPS, but HTTP works too

Tags: http, nginx, https

How can I do to my site works with HTTP and HTTPS, but if user type site.com the priority is HTTPS, but if user force http with http://example.com, so works too.

I'm using NGINX.

Comment: Chrome does this by default since version 90. What browser are you testing this with, and what's the behavior you're seeing?

Comment: Are you asking how you would do an automatic redirect to https when someone goes to a http url?

Comment: @Evert I'm using Chrome, but when I access example.com go to HTTP and not to HTTPS.

Comment: @Elijah no. I would like HTTPS was priority, but if force http, worked too.

Comment: @Nicolas that might be because you visited it before.

Comment: But if I use a private tab the problem occur in same way.